# Matplotlib: How to draw edge lines in Arc - patches

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given a center and two angles of a rotated ellipse of `Arc` from `matplotlib.patches`, I want to plot the two lines starting from the center of the Arc to the ends of the Arc.

Here is a piece of code that does that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

r = 2 #Radius
a = 0.2*r #width 
b = 0.5*r #height

#center of the ellipse
x = 0.5
y = 0.5

ax.add_patch(Arc((x, y), a, b, angle = 20,
             theta1=0, theta2=120, 
             edgecolor='b', lw=1.1))
#Now look for the ends of the Arc and manually set the limits
ax.plot([x,0.687],[y,0.567], color='r',lw=1.1)
ax.plot([x,0.248],[y,0.711], color='r',lw=1.1)

plt.show()
```

Which results in

[image: ellipse].

Here the red lines were drawn looking carefully at the ends of the arc. However, as `Arc` does not allow to fill the arc for optimization, I wonder if there is a way to do it automatically for any center and angles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center) an ellipse in its polar form looks like
>
> [image]

Using this you may calculate the end points of the lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

r = 2 #Radius
a = 0.2*r #width 
b = 0.5*r #height

#center of the ellipse
x = 0.5; y = 0.5

# angle
alpha = 20

ax.add_patch(Arc((x, y), a, b, angle = alpha,
             theta1=0, theta2=120, 
             edgecolor='b', lw=1.1))

def ellipse(x0,y0,a,b,alpha,phi):
    r = a*b/np.sqrt((b*np.cos(phi))**2 + (a*np.sin(phi))**2)
    return [x0+r*np.cos(phi+alpha), y0+r*np.sin(phi+alpha)]

x1,y1 = ellipse(x, y, a/2., b/2., np.deg2rad(alpha), np.deg2rad(0))
ax.plot([x,x1],[y,y1], color='r',lw=1.1)

x2,y2 = ellipse(x, y, a/2., b/2., np.deg2rad(alpha), np.deg2rad(120))
ax.plot([x,x2],[y,y2], color='r',lw=1.1)

ax.set_aspect("equal")
plt.show()
```

[image]